# Test Whether the screen is ON/OFF in iphone

Tags: ios, ios5, uiaccelerometer

I am developing a application to test whether the iphone screen is OFF or ON and i tried the code of accelerometer that specified in stack overflow it working well for screen on status but when i turn off the screen the accelerometer is not deactivating.

So i am getting doubt about the fact that did really accelerometer get deactivate automatically when the screen turns off. If anybody having clear idea about it please share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application are paused when it sleep. You should realize a background task for it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20